# How can I 'add' two NSLayoutDimensions?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutanchor

Adding two `NSLayoutDimension` objects doesn't really make sense, but I'm trying to set the height of a container view to the height of two subviews with dynamic heights.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to do, where `dynamic view 1` and `dynamic view 2` both have dynamic heights, and the container view sizes according to the sizes of the two dynamic views.

```
 ----------------
|                |
| dynamic view 1 |
|                |
|                |
| dynamic view 2 |
|                |
 ----------------
```

Programmatically, something along the lines of:

```
heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: dynamicView1.heightAnchor + dynamicView2.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

But this obviously returns an error. What's the best way to set up these constraints?

Comment: what does the error say?!

Comment: `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'NSLayoutDimension' operands`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example above, all I needed to add was a bottom constraint to `dynamicView2`.

```
dynamicView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```